# Why isn't my jQuery functioning correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so im trying to make an accordion style drop down menu, and for some reason my jQuery isn't working. 
This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion-control").click(function(){ 
        $(div).hide();
    });
});
```

It should hiding all divs when something in the accordion-control class is clicked. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: The *first* thing you should do is check the browser's console.  This is undoubtedly producing an error telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: The selector used is illegel, try $("div").

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. I misplaced the default jQuery import.

Answer (score 2):

`div`  is `string`

```
$("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion-control").click(function(){ 
        $("div").hide();
    });
});
```

You're referring to **div** as if it were an object, but it should be a string: **"div"**